# Cannot zoom or pan in render mode

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

am on blender 2.81 having issues with render mode. In solid mode I can pan and zoom just fine, but when I got to render mode zooming, panning, and anything gets really buggy, very jumpy and almost not working.

Comment: Sounds like your having performance issues and the render isn't updating fast enough. Does that happen only with Cycles or also with Eevee?

Comment: it happens on both. I've tried changing settings but not sure what's optimal for a mac tbh. here's my set up https://share.getcloudapp.com/Jruw2yYe

Comment: I can confirm this - in 2.81 using Eevee in the viewport is a bit slower, which can be frustrating. You could turn down anti-aliasing levels in *Preferences->Viewport->Quality*. Or alternatively decrease viewport resolution in *Render Tab->Performance->Viewport*

Comment: ah ok thanks let me try

Comment: Preferences->Viewport->Quality omg that worked great, thank you!!!!

Comment: where would the render tab performance be, the sampling?

Comment: https://share.getcloudapp.com/04ukBnl1

Comment: not seeing it in performance tab